# System.AccessViolationException Error c++ VS 2010 Express (Easy Code)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error

Every time I want to run this code I get this error message from VS c++ 2010 Express:

> Eine nicht behandelte Ausnahme des Typs
>   "System.AccessViolationException" ist in Automat.exe aufgetreten.
>
> Zusätzliche Informationen: Es wurde versucht, im geschützten Speicher
>   zu lesen oder zu schreiben. Dies ist haufig ein Hinweis darauf, dass
>   anderer Speicher beschädigt ist.

Here is the error message translated to English using Google Translate:

> An unhandled exception of type "System.AccessViolationException
>   'occurred in Automat.exe.
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory
>   was. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

And here is my Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{int g[5]={14,28,24,24,12},ag[3]={30,25,17},w[5]={0,0,0,0,0},a;
 float e,p[3]={1.2,1.0,0.95},s=0;
 while(1)
    {while(1)
        {printf("\n1)Drink1 1.2Euro");
         printf("\n2)Drink2 1Euro");
         printf("\n3)Drink3 0.95Euro");
         printf("\nWaehlen sie ein Getraenk aus:    ");
         scanf("%f",&a);
         if(a==123456)
             {printf("\nEs sind noch folgende Getraenke vorhanden:");
              printf("\n%dxDrink1\n%dxDrink2\n%dxDrink3",ag[0],ag[1],ag[2]);
              printf("\nEs ist noch folgendes Wechselgeld vorhanden:");
              printf("\n%fx1Euro\n%fx50Cent\n%fx20Cent\n%fx10Cent\n%fx5Cent\n",g[0],g[1],g[2],g[3],g[4]);
              break;
             }
         else
             {if(ag[a-1]==0)
                {printf("\n\nDas Ausgewaehlte Getraenk ist nicht mehr verfuegbar\n");
                }
              else
                {if(a==1 || a==2 || a==3)
                    {break;
                    }
                }
            }

         printf("\n\nIhr Auswahl ist ungueltig!\n");
        }
     a--;
     printf("\n\n Bitte werfen sie %.2f Euro ein\n",&p[a]);
     while(s<p[a])
        {while(1)
            {printf("\nDerzeit:   %f\nEinwurf:   \n",s);
             scanf("%f",&e);
             if(e==2 || e==1 || e==0.5 || e==0.2 || e==0.1 || e==0.05)
                {break;
                }
             printf("\nDer eingeworfene Wert ist ungueltig!\n");
            }
          s=s+e;
        }
     ag[a]--;
     s=s-p[a];
     if(s==0)
        {printf("\n\nGeniessen sie ihr Getraenk!\n");
        }
     else
        {printf("\nSie bekommen noch %f Euro\n",s);
         while(s-1>0)
            {w[0]++;
             s=s-1;
            }
         while(s-0.5>0)
            {w[1]++;
             s=s-0.5;
            }
         while(s-0.2>0)
            {w[2]++;
             s=s-0.2;
            }
         while(s-0.1>0)
            {w[3]++;
             s=s-0.1;
            }
         while(s-0.05>0)
            {w[4]++;
             s=s-0.05;
            }
         printf("\nIhr Wechselgeld:");
         printf("\n%fx1Euro\n%fx50Cent\n%fx20Cent\n%fx10Cent\n%fx5Cent",w[0],w[1],w[2],w[3],w[4]);
         printf("\n\nGeniessen sie ihr Getraenk!\n");
         g[0]=g[0]-w[0];
         g[1]=g[1]-w[1];
         g[2]=g[2]-w[2];
         g[3]=g[3]-w[3];
         g[4]=g[4]-w[4];
        }
    }


 getch(); 
 return 0; 
}
```

**When Debugging I found out, that it doesn't even think the first statement (if(a==123456)) is true when I type in 123456.**

Please help.

Comment: **1.** You tagged this C++ when it is a C question. **2.** It is better to type out the error message rather than link to a screenshot. **3.** It is useful to provide an English translation if your error message is non-English. I have edited your question to reflect all three of these points.

Comment: As an aside, your code is a nightmare to read. Rather than variable names such as g, ag, w, e, p, s - use names which actually mean something to the reader.

Comment: Sorry first question. Thanks for the Tipps.

Comment: @ebyrob Are you referring to the comment at the top of his code? If so, that isn't a copyright statement - [see here](http://tinyurl.com/5minutescodetranslation).

Comment: Note: It's probably also not necessary to include large comment blocks in questions such as this.  Usually a low-level flaw such as an access violation won't be much related to program design goals.   (yes, sorry I originally thought that was a copyright, not comments)

Comment: @ebyrob Good point, I've edited it out of his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be reading an integer(`a`) in `scanf` using `%f` format specifier. Use `%d` instead.

Comment: @5minutes **"When Debugging...(if(a==123456))...type in 123456."**  How do you even get to that line, isn't `scanf` raising the access violation?  It sure should be!  Either way, see the above answer.  `a` should be a `float` or use `%d` instead.